# Reduplication of the noun 小时 in 走了半个多小时小时

Tags: meaning-in-context, time

Chinese uses reduplication of verbs and adjectives all the time, but I can't find any explanation of reduplication of nouns to explain **小时小时** in this sentence:

(from a Mandarin Companion reader, 地心游记, chapter 5. Our heroes are out of water...)

> 不管怎么样，我到水就好。我们一起跟着老许去找水，**走了半个多小时小时**，我们听到了地下河水的声音。

I interpret 半个多小时 as "more than half an hour" (but less than an hour).  What does the repetition of 小时 mean here?

Comment: I believe it is a typo in the book.

Comment: Agree, it’s a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a typo. We never use reduplication of noun 小时.

There is another typo in this sentence. 我到水就好 should be 找到水就好.

Comment: The second typo (我 for 找) is mine.